# Transimpedance amplifier design advice

Tags: operational-amplifier, phototransistor, transimpedance

I'm working on a transimpedance amplifier for a phototransistor in order to create a sensor that counts objects falling down a pipe.

This is the sensor: https://www.digikey.it/short/0vq01q7h

Datasheet: https://www.ttelectronics.com/TTElectronics/media/ProductFiles/Optoelectronics/Datasheets/OPB708-709-740-748.pdf (Model name: OPB742)

And this is the opamp: https://www.digikey.it/short/zjbbjrj0

Datasheet: https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/TL072.pdf

The power lines available on the board without adding another buck converter are +12V, +5V, +3V3 and of course GND.
I basically need to translate the current flowing through the phototransistor into a readable voltage that will be fed into a binary counter or any microcontroller (passing through a Schmitt trigger before). When there is no object in front of the sensor there will a current I_min, and when an object is present a current I_max because of the increased reflectivity.
The circuit needs to map I_min to GND (or +5V) and I_max to +5V (or GND) so that it can be treated as a binary state.

Keep in mind that I need to improve the response time of the phototransistor as much as possible in order for the system to have a good bandwidth.

This is the circuit I've come up with:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fffImT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the schematic I've treated the phototransistor as a current source for simplicity.

In a steady state condition:

V_out = V_plus - I_c * (BASE_GAIN + VARIABLE_GAIN)

The idea is to calibrate it in this way:

- While the sensor is in a "no-object condition", so I_min, regulate the trimmer OFFSET such that V_OUT is set to +5V (or the maximum the opamp can handle, a bit less)
- Put the object in front so that the current rises to I_max, and regulate the trimmer VARIABLE_GAIN in order to have the sum of the feedback resistors high enough to bring V_OUT to 0V

Here are my doubts:

1. Is it a good choice to connect the transistor collector to the highest available voltage (12V)? My knowledge about phototranistors is not deep enough, but as far as I understand, the response time sould improve with a higher collector-emitter voltage (?) which in this case is held constant at around +7V by the op-amp. Without reaching the breakdown voltage of course.
2. How do you think I could improve the stability of the system? For sure capacitor C1 is needed, but should I do something more?

Comment: Watch out for the common-mode limits of the amplifier - you have 7V at the inputs but only a 5v supply.

Comment: No real need to use a TIA - use a voltage comparator.

Comment: There are 11 possible models in the data sheet you linked to, What, exactly, is the model you are interested in? Edit your question to include that.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast if you refer to the sensor, just before the datasheet I linked the page
 of the specific model containing the name. I'm gonna edit the post as you suggested to make it more clear